# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

I've read through other posts regarding this error and I thought I solved the problem, but I'm still having trouble.

I have included the necessary `self` argument in the appropriate space, but I am still receiving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 30, in <module>
    JohnSmith = CheckingAccount(20000)
  File "...", line 18, in __init__
    BankAccount.__init__(self, initBal)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

---

```
class BankAccount (object):
        # define class for bank account
        def __init__ (self):
            # initialize bank account w/ balance of zero
            self.balance = 0
        def deposit (self, amount):
            # deposit the given amount into account
            self.balance = self.balance + amount
        def withdraw (self, amount):
            # withdraw the given amount from account
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
        def getBalance (self): 
            # return account balance
            return self.balance

class CheckingAccount (BankAccount):
    def __init__ (self, initBal):
        BankAccount.__init__(self, initBal)
        self.checkRecord = {}
    def processCheck (self, number, toWho, amount):
        self.withdraw(amount)
        self.checkRecord[number] = (toWho, amount)
    def checkInfo (self, number):
        if self.checkRecord.has_key(number):
            return self.checkRecord [ number ]
        else:
            return 'No Such Check'

# create checking account
JohnSmith = CheckingAccount(20000)
JohnSmith.processCheck(19371554951,'US Bank - Mortgage', 1200)
print (JohnSmith.checkInfo(19371554951))
JohnSmith.deposit(1000)
JohnSmith.withdraw(4000)
JohnSmith.withdraw(3500)
```

Comment: `BankAccount.__init__` only takes `self` as an argument, but you are also passing it `initBal`. So either change `BankAccount.__init__` to take an initial balance or stop passing it one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350161/typeerror-init-takes-1-positional-argument-but-4-were-given)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to redefine `BankAccount` as

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self, init_bal=0):
        self.balance = init_bal

     # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write the constructor of `BankAccount` as

```
def __init__(self, initbal=0)
    self.balance = initbal
```

Comment: Thank you both; I made the suggested changes and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CheckingAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, initBal):
        super().__init__()
        self.balance = initBal
        self.checkRecord = {}
```

Something like that will get you started. I also changed

```
if self.checkRecord.has_key(number):
```

to

```
if number in self.checkRecord:
```

You dont ever use `initBal` or assign it to a variable, I assume it should be `self.balance`

I also used super here, which will only work on python 3. It allows you to change the name of `BankAccount` in the future without having to refactor your code. If you can use it, I highly recommend it, it is a good practice. Otherwise the solution is

```
class CheckingAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, initBal):
        BankAccount.__init__(self)
        self.balance = initBal
        self.checkRecord = {}
```