# Don't understand cause of TypeError about number of arguments when attempting to create instance of class

Tags: python, class

Main code that is a `BankAccount` class that has the following attributes
listed in the function:

```
class BankAccount():
    #Implementation of __init__ function
    def __init__(self):
        #Declare balance and initialize with 0.0
        self.balance =0.0
        #Declare transaction_history as type of list
        self.transaction_history=[]

    #Implementation of get_balance method
    def get_balance(self):
        #check self.balance is equal to ""
        if self.balance == "":
            #Display an error message through TypeError
            raise TypeError("You must enter a number")
        return self.balance

    def set_balance(self,balance):
        #check balance is equal to ""
        if balance == "":
            #Display an error message through TypeError
            raise TypeError("You must enter a number")

        #check balance is less than 0 or not
        if balance<=0 or not isinstance(balance,float) :
            #raise an error message
            raise ValueError('Error: Not greater than 0')
        else:
            #assign balance to self.balance
            self.balance=balance

    #Implementation of get_transaction_history method
    def get_transaction_history(self):
        #check self.transaction_history is equal to ""
        if self.transaction_history == "":
            #Display an error message through TypeError
            raise TypeError("You must enter a number")
        return self.transaction_history

    #Implementation of set_transaction_history method
    def set_transaction_history(self,transaction_history):
        #check transaction_history is equal to ""
        if transaction_history == "":
            #Display an error message through TypeError
            raise TypeError("You must enter a number")
        self.transaction_history.append(transaction_history)

    #Implementation of get_avg_transaction method
    def get_avg_transaction(self):
        #check length of self.transaction_history is equal to 0
        if len(self.transaction_history)==0:
            #Display an error message through ValueError
            raise ValueError('Error: No transactions have been made\n')

        #return the resultant value of
        # sum(self.transaction_history)/len(self.transaction_history)
        return sum(self.transaction_history)/len(self.transaction_history)

    #Implementation of despost method with parameter amount
    def deposit(self,amount):
       if amount is not None:
           #Display statement
           print("Error: Not greater than 0")

       #Display statement
       print('You must enter a number\n')
       #calculate self.balance
       self.balance = self.balance + amount
       #append the amount to self.transaction_history
       self.transaction_history.append(amount)

    #Implementation of withdraw method with parameter amount
    def withdraw(self,amount):
        if (not isinstance(amount,float) and not isinstance(amount,int)) or amount<=0:
            #Display an error message through ValueError
            raise ValueError('Error: Not greater than 0')
        else:
            #calculate self.balance
            self.balance= self.balance - amount
            #call set_tranasaction_history method
            self.set_transaction_history(-amount)
```

Test Code:

```
from Lab5_Error_handling import BankAccount

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the bank account
    print("Creating the bank account:")
    bank_account = BankAccount(100)

    # Attempt to get average transactions
    print("\nGetting the average transactions (first time)")
    try:
        print(bank_account.get_avg_transaction())
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error: No transactions have been made")
    except:
        print("YOU HAVE DONE SOMETHING WRONG; YOU SHOULD NOT BE SEEING THIS")

    # Deposit money
    print("\nDepositing money")
    try:
        bank_account.deposit(-200)
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error: Not greater than 0")
    except:
        print("YOU HAVE DONE SOMETHING WRONG; YOU SHOULD NOT BE SEEING THIS")

    # Deposit money
    print("\nDepositing money")
    try:
        bank_account.deposit("200")
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
    except:
        print("YOU HAVE DONE SOMETHING WRONG; YOU SHOULD NOT BE SEEING THIS")


    bank_account.deposit(200)
    # Withdraw money
    print("\nWithdrawing money")
    try:
        bank_account.withdraw("100")
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
    except:
        print("YOU HAVE DONE SOMETHING WRONG; YOU SHOULD NOT BE SEEING THIS")

    print("\nWithdrawing money")
    try:
        bank_account.withdraw(100000)
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error: Not greater than the balance")
    except:
        print("YOU HAVE DONE SOMETHING WRONG; YOU SHOULD NOT BE SEEING THIS")

    bank_account.withdraw(100)

    # Get average transactions
    print("\nGetting the average transactions (second time)")
    try:
        print(bank_account.get_avg_transaction())
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error: Not greater than 0")
    except:
        print("YOU HAVE DONE SOMETHING WRONG; YOU SHOULD NOT BE SEEING THIS")

    # Get Balance
    print("\nBalance: ",bank_account.get_balance())
```

I am getting this error though:

```
line 6, in <module>
    bank_account = BankAccount(100)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How would I get rid of this error? Would I need to add something to the `__init__()` function or is there something wrong entirely with my code?

Comment: you're passing `100` to your `BankAccount` class initialization, but it expects no arguments (`    def __init__(self):`) (or, it expects 1 `self` but it's getting 2, `self` and `100`)

Comment: The short answer is to change `BankAccount(100)` to `BankAccount()` since `__init__()` only declares the `self` argument which is passed in automatically. For a longer answer, what are you trying to do by passing in `100`? The answer to this question will help us give a more complete answer.

Comment: Have a look at the BankAccount init method. It always initialises the balance to 0. It doesn't accept a number as an argument. If you want it to do something different, rewrite it to do that.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
The error message is clear, especially after you look up the meaning on line.  Where are you confused.
You posted over 10 lines of code for a 10-line problem; this is excessive.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the answer to this question is. Creating the bank account:

Getting the average transactions (first time)
Error: No Transactions have been made 

Depositing money
Error: Not greater than 0
You must enter a number


Depositing money
Error: Not greater than 0
You must enter a number

Withdraw Money:
Error: Not greater than 0
You must enter a number


Withdrawing money
Error: Not greater than the balance

Getting the average transactions (second time)
50.0

Balance:  200

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_init\_\_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312491/init-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given) (It's the same problem/example with BankAccount class and `__init__ (self)`.)

Comment: Off-topic: The code in your class definition shouldn't have been double spaced like that—it actually makes it less understandable—and many (most?) of the comments it in are either useless or redundant (or both). Strongly suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you are trying to pass in too many arguments when you create a `BankAccount` object. There are two possible solutions:

1. Don't pass in any arguments by changing `BankAccount(100)` to `BankAccount()`.
2. Change `__init__()` to accept another argument. I will assume that this argument represents the initial balance:

   ```
   class BankAccount():

       #Implementation of __init__ function

       def __init__(self, initial_balance):

           #Declare balance and initialize with 0.0

           self.balance = initial_balance

           #Declare transaction_history as type of list

           self.transaction_history=[]
   ```

   Here the `initial_balance` is required. You can use a default value instead if you want it to be optional. I will leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I have shared the answer in the comments section